# How to restart a model training from a check point in Tensorflow.js with Node.js (tfjs-node)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js

I'm training models and need to create check points of training models and restart the model training from saved level with check points. Is this possible with tfjs-node ? if so please guide..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your model using the `model.save()` method, with a file:// URL, e.g., 
`await model.save('file:///tmp/my_model');`.

Later, you can load the model back using `tf.loadModel()`, also with a file:// URL, e.g., `const model = await tf.loadModel('file:///tmp/my_model/model.json');` The loaded model retains the weight parameters from previous training and can be trained further following a `compile()` call.

Note that currently TensorFlow.js has a limitation in that it doesn't save the state of optimizers. Therefore, if you use one of the stateful optimizers, e.g., 'adam', 'rmsprop', instead of the default, stateless one (i.e., 'sgd'), the states of the optimizers will be forgotten after the save and load.